# How do I create prongs that are cut into a curve ring and that cover a object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, boolean-modifier

[image]

I want to create a ring where the diamonds are jaded into it's sides with prongs that are part of the ring and are connected to it.

This is what I have achieved so far.

[image: m]